# React Beginner Having Problems Adapting Material-UI Example Into React Project. State Not Working the Same Way Hooks was

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm still a React beginner, but I'm trying to build a form for a project management web application.

I'm using material-ui. I based my code off one of the select box component examples from the material-ui docs.

I just recently figured out how React-Hooks work, and the example was making use of this feature.

I'm trying to change form.js to update the multiple select box based on the state of App.js through props, instead of relying on the functional component hooks.

It seems to work when I leave hooks in place for personName, but as soon as I try to change it to something like props.accountSelected I start seeing errors and the multiple selected chips don't show up anymore.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Form'

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
      projectName: '',
      accountField: {
        selected: {value: 'jacks', label: 'Jacks'},
        options:[
          {value: 'walmart', label: 'Walmart'},
          {value: 'zellers', label: 'Zellers'},
          {value: 'partyplace', label: 'Party Place'},
          {value: 'majorbank', label: 'Major bank'}
        ]
      }
  }
}

setAccountsSelected(selected) {
  console.log('>> [App.js] (setAccountsSelected) ',selected)
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form 
        accountFieldoptions={this.state.accountField.options}
        setAccountsSelected={this.setAccountsSelected}
        accountSelected={this.state.accountField.selected}
      />
    </div>
  );

  }
}
export default App;
```

Form.js (works but selected chips no longer show up)

```
import React from 'react';
//import Select from 'react-select'; // https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));


const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

let names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}



export default function Form(props) {
  console.log('>> [Form.js] props = ',props)

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  names = [...props.accountFieldoptions];

  console.log('>> [Form.js] names = ', names)

  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    //setPersonName(event.target.value);
    props.setAccountsSelected(event.target.value);
  }

  // function handleChangeMultiple(event) {
  //   const { options } = event.target;
  //   const value = [];
  //   for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
  //     if (options[i].selected) {
  //       value.push(options[i].value);
  //     }
  //   }
  //   setPersonName(value);

  // }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-accounts">Account</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-accounts" />}
          renderValue={selected => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
              {selected.map(value => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name.label} value={name.label} style={getStyles(name.label, personName, theme)}>
              {name.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Form.js (throws error: TypeError: personName.indexOf is not a function getStyles
src/Form.js:62)

```
import React from 'react';
//import Select from 'react-select'; // https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));


const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

let names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}



export default function Form(props) {
  console.log('>> [Form.js] props = ',props)

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  names = [...props.accountFieldoptions];

  console.log('>> [Form.js] names = ', names)

  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    //setPersonName(event.target.value);
    props.setAccountsSelected(event.target.value);
  }

  // function handleChangeMultiple(event) {
  //   const { options } = event.target;
  //   const value = [];
  //   for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
  //     if (options[i].selected) {
  //       value.push(options[i].value);
  //     }
  //   }
  //   setPersonName(value);

  // }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-accounts">Account</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={props.accountSelected}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-accounts" />}
          renderValue={selected => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
              {selected.map(value => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name.label} value={name.label} style={getStyles(name.label, props.accountSelected, theme)}>
              {name.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Original Example I based my code off of:

https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleChangeMultiple(event) {
    const { options } = event.target;
    const value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }
    setPersonName(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple">Name</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name} style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
          renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-chip">Chip</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
          renderValue={selected => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
              {selected.map(value => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name} style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl className={clsx(classes.formControl, classes.noLabel)}>
        <Select
          multiple
          displayEmpty
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-placeholder" />}
          renderValue={selected => {
            if (selected.length === 0) {
              return <em>Placeholder</em>;
            }

            return selected.join(', ');
          }}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          <MenuItem disabled value="">
            <em>Placeholder</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name} style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="select-multiple-native">
          Native
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          native
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChangeMultiple}
          inputProps={{
            id: 'select-multiple-native',
          }}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <option key={name} value={name}>
              {name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and why it works with Hooks, but not with props?

Comment: `constructor(props) {  super(props);` Not sure if this is the issue, but see if this resolves. You are supposed to pass props to super

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the `selected` as array in Material UI multiple select.

The Material UI example declared `personName` as array in the useState hook here:

```js
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
```

Maybe you can try changing your selected App's state to array like the following and see if it helps:

```js
this.state = {
      projectName: "",
      accountField: {
        // selected: { value: "jacks", label: "Jacks" },
        selected: ["jacks"],
        options: [
          { value: "walmart", label: "Walmart" },
          { value: "zellers", label: "Zellers" },
          { value: "partyplace", label: "Party Place" },
          { value: "majorbank", label: "Major bank" }
        ]
      }
    };
```